# How to add extra keys on top of ios keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

In termius, when you open the keyboard, there are extra keys on top of the keyboard as you can see in the picture.

How can I make this in swift?

[image: termius]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add button to field:

```
let keyboardToolbar = UIToolbar()
keyboardToolbar.sizeToFit()
keyboardToolbar.isTranslucent = false
keyboardToolbar.barTintColor = UIColor.white

let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(
    barButtonSystemItem: .done, 
    target: self, 
    action: #selector(someFunction)
)
addButton.tintColor = UIColor.black
keyboardToolbar.items = [addButton]
textView.inputAccessoryView = keyboardToolbar
```

or another:

```
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 60))
      button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
      button.setTitle("NEXT", for: .normal)
      button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
      button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self. yourButton), for: .touchUpInside)
textField.inputAccessoryView = button
```

SwiftUI solution:

```
struct TestTextfield: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: String
    var keyType: UIKeyboardType
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField {
        let textfield = UITextField()
      textfield.keyboardType = keyType
        let toolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: textfield.frame.size.width, height: 44))
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(textfield.doneButtonTapped(button:)))
        toolBar.items = [doneButton]
        toolBar.setItems([doneButton], animated: true)
        textfield.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
        return textfield
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: Context) {
        uiView.text = text

    }
}

extension  UITextField{
    @objc func doneButtonTapped(button:UIBarButtonItem) -> Void {
       self.resignFirstResponder()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIToolbar with any buttons you want, all you need to add that toolbar to the inputAccessoryView of the input textfield. like code below.

```
let bar = UIToolbar()
let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self,action:#selector(doneTapped))
bar.items = [doneButton]
bar.sizeToFit()
inputTextField.inputAccessoryView = bar
```